# Computing matrix-vector calculus derivatives

Tags: calculus, matrices, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

$x, a$ in $\mathbb R^n$, $A$ in $\mathbb  R^{n\times n}$. Compute $d(x^T a)/dx$ and $d(x^T A x)/dx$.

I'm not sure about how to think about these and how to do these. Can someone explain how to derive the expressions for the two?

Finally, what happens when we have $A$ and $X$, BOTH in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, and we want to find $dTrace(XA)/dX$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the convention that members of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are column
vectors. Recall that 
$$
x^{T}a=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}a_{i}
$$
and for a scalar $c$,
$$
\frac{dc}{dx}\equiv\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{dc}{dx_{1}}\\
\frac{dc}{dx_{2}}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{dc}{dx_{n}}
\end{array}\right).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{d\left(x^{T}a\right)}{dx}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
\vdots\\
a_{n}
\end{array}\right)=a.
$$
You can follow the same arguments to get
$$
\frac{d\left(x^{T}Ax\right)}{dx}=2Ax.
$$
See a list of identities at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the same arguments to get 2Ax. This is what I have: x^T A x = sum, j from 1 to n, xj, times sum, i from 1 to n, xi aij. So d(x^T A X)/dx =< d(double sum from the previous sentence)/dx1, d( double sum from prev)/dx2, ......d(double sum from prev sentence)/d(xn)>. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^ta=a^tx$ and so
$$
\frac{d(x^tA)}{dx}=\frac{d}{dh}a^t(x+h)|_{h=0}=a^t.
$$
Similarly, since $h^tAx=x^tA^th$, 
$$
\frac{d(x^tAx)}{dx}=\frac{d}{dh}(x+h)^tA(x+h)|_{h=0}=\frac{d}{dh}(x^tAh+h^tAx)|_{h=0}=x^t(A+A^t).
$$
Finally, since
$$
tr(XA)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij}A_{ji}
$$
we have
$$
\frac{d tr(XA)}{d X_{ij}}=A_{ji},
$$
which gives
$$
\frac{d tr(XA)}{d X}=A^t.
$$
All this must be interpreted properly if used to make other computations!

Comment: For the first one, shouldn't it be a instead of a transpose?

Comment: You saw my deduction. So why do you ask?

Comment: par's answer above concluded otherwise.

Comment: The confusion is: His answer is a and yours is a transpose.

Comment: So what? That's the unfortunate nature of the site: sometimes you need to choose. :)

Comment: Oh I think I get it now. You are just using a different convention?

Comment: Nope. I am using the same convention. Since you ask, "par"'s 4th line is wrong (it is important o be consistent in conventions).

Comment: Could you explain why the 4th line is wrong? the  derivative there is a column vector. And "a" is a column vector as well.

Comment: Sorry, I already used to much time for this question. I stop here.